# what versions to use when using Spring-ws spring-integration and spring-security altogether

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ws, spring-integration

I'm using Spring-integration 2.0.0 and wanted to secure the calls to the web services exposed by Spring integration. So I used the secured channels and it works fine so far using Spring-core 3.0.5 and Spring security 3.0.5.

But then I wanted to use the WSS interceptors of Spring web services. And then came the following problem : 
when I declare the XwsSecurityInterceptor like this :

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
    <description>
        This interceptor validates incoming messages according to the policy defined in 'securityPolicy.xml'.
        The policy defines that all incoming requests must have a UsernameToken with a password digest in it.
        The actual authentication is performed by the Spring Security callback handler.
    </description>
    <property name="secureResponse" value="false"/>
    <property name="policyConfiguration"
              value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml"/>
    <property name="callbackHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get this stack :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [SES/Operations/Logging/applicationContext-security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler#b0dbb' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler] while setting bean property 'callbackHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler#b0dbb' defined in class path resource [SES/Operations/Logging/applicationContext-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/AuthenticationManager
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3391)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1309)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler#b0dbb' defined in class path resource [SES/Operations/Logging/applicationContext-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/AuthenticationManager
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
 ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/AuthenticationManager
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
 at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
 at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1154)
 at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:405)
 at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:164)
 at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224)
 at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:305)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:407)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1319)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.AuthenticationManager
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 ... 43 more
```

my maven dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
   <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
   <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

  <!-- Spring integration dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

I guess this has something to do with a dependency problem as I read that some packages have been reworked between 2.x and 3.x versions. Please note that I had to exclude transitive dependency from spring-ws-security to spring-beans as it was bringing the 2.0.6 version of spring beans which were conflicting with 3.0.5 release of the same jar.

So my question is : what versions of the different Spring modules (Spring-ws, Spring-integration, Spring-security, Spring-framework) should I use ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions should work together. As spring-ws version 2.0 was released this week your problem should be solved for production too.

Comment: hi iwein, I upgraded spring-WS to the latest 2.0 snapshot and it worked fine. Thanks for your help!